# Get element name when click on the webBrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control, mshtml

I want to get element name and pass it to c# when user click on the element. How can I do it?
I can get the element with doc.all but I need to do it when user click on the element.

Comment: I know and do it very well and i know how can play with elements. but time is so important.

Comment: Please, tell your exact conditions (winforms, wpf, asp, silverlight), the control you are referring to (the .NET one or an external library) and post the code you have written so far.

Comment: Wpf. Mshtml. condition: xaml

Comment: OK. I don't have too much experience on Mshtml; but I am sure that there are quite a few people who can help you out. To attract the right helpers, better update the tags: include "mshtml" and "wpf".

Comment: Thank you. I think just myself can solve this problem :(

Comment: No problem. But, to be honest, I don't see the real problem to do it by your own (bear in mind that the idea is: firstly try it by your own and, only when it is impossible to go through, come here to ask); all the web controls behave more or less the same and are pretty intuitive. It shouldn't be too difficult to do a quick research to find a working code under the exact conditions you are looking for, understand it and adapt it to your exact requirements.

Comment: @HamedKhosravi, if you like to solve it by yourself, search for `ObjectForScripting`, this is how you could call C# from JavaScript.